# An app which takes from you a time and sends a message at that time

Tags: android

I am new at android and I am trying to make an android app which takes from you the time and sends a message to user at that time. Can someone tell me the steps to follow so I can make this app.

Comment: Send a message? Via email, via sms, via what? How will that message be displayed? Via toast, via popup Activity/Dialog, via the Notification Manager? Would you mind using an existing Calendar app to do the work for you? Or would you rather do the app from scratch and use something like AlarmManager? What Android programming tutorial have you googled for thus far? Would you mind doing some of that googling first and come back when you've tried a few things? We'll be happy to take a look at your code when you get stuck somewhere.

Comment: you are right but I want to learn how it is made.

Comment: You didn't even answer any of my initial clarifying questions. It would have been ok to answer them. Don't be afraid to look foolish when asking and answering questions. That's really the best and fastest way to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually pretty simple. One way to do this (may not be the simplist but would give you good experience with a bunch of the android framework:

1. Register a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)
2. Gather the information (message, destination, time) from the user using UI elements.
3. Send an [intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) to the BroadcastReciever with the time specified.
4. Send the sms from the BroadcastReceiver, using [SmsManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html).

This would also give you a lot of opportunity to add to this app, you can learn to use [Content Providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) to keep track of the current 'Pending Messages' and give the user an option to view and edit them.